# Read files from deeply nested sub-directories and rename them with sub-directory full path name in R

Tags: r, file, directory

I have a directory containing files in very deeply nested directories. They are results from a simulation.
Here is the structure of the directories and sub-directories.
[image: file tree, showing one complete branch]

only one complete branch is shown. the files are found only in the directories at the end (i.e. 1 2 3 4 5 6 sub-directories). In total, there are 96 end sub-directories.

I am trying to read the files (*.mass) files, rename them according to its parent directories and create a single DataFrame, from which I can plot the different variables. naming it this way is important to identify the different cases, because at each level, each sub-directory represent keeping a some variables constant and varying another.

I tried list.files() but it wouldn´t give me a list of all subdirectories and file names in a systematic manner.

Note: All the files have the same parent Name, e.g. Test1 but different extensions e.g. Test1.vtk, Test1.mass, Test1.prb etc, but I´m only interested in the Test1.mass files, which is only 1 per case.

Comment: When you use `list.files`, set `recursive = TRUE` to search subdirectories. Use `pattern = "\\.mass$"` to match only files that end in `.mass`. So, make sure you working directory is the `Inf` directory you show, then `mass_files = list.files(pattern = "\\.mass$", recursive = TRUE)` will give you a vector of the paths to all the mass files. You could further specify `pattern = "Test1\\.mass"`, if you want to be more specific.

Comment: *"rename them according to its parent directories"* is unspecific, can you be more clear? Do you just want to replace the path-separator (`/` or `\ `) with an underscore, space, or something?

Comment: I would like to name the files in a way that shows the variables I´m working with. e.g.  Inf_veg_R1D1_MT_1 will be the name of a file in the path on the left of the orange line, which can be interpreted as follows: there is infiltration, Rain intensity 1, Rain Duration 1, presence of microtopography and the topography is type 1. I don´t know if I make sense here, but if there´s a better method to represent the different cases, I will be happy to apply it instead. Thanks

Comment: Something like `fn <- list.files(pattern="\\.mass$", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE); file.rename(fn, gsub("[/\\\\]", "_", fn))`? (Caution, don't just "try" that command without verifying the `gsub` works.)

Comment: @r2evans The method works fine for reading and renaming, but I must say it´s a bit dangerous. the files are removed from their respective locations, renamed and copied to the working directory. Thanks for the warning too.

Comment: Dangerous? Perhaps I misunderstood your statement: *"rename them according to its parent directories"*.

Comment: You understood well. I probably shouldn´t used the word "dangerous". It was just dangerous for me because at first I didn`t understand how it works until I tried it and found that the files have been moved from their original location. But it does the job just as I wanted. thanks

Comment: If you need to move them back, then assuming files did not have a `_` in them before renaming, it shouldn't be hard to just reverse the `gsub`.